# Javascript slideshow array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, slideshow

I want to make an automatic text changing array with javascript, everything looks perfectly fine but it's not working. When I launch my webpage it's just a blank empty space where the text should be at.

Javascript:

```
    <script>
var quote_i = Math.floor(Math.random()*quote_array.length);
var quote_array = ["bandymas","dar vienas","test"];
var quote_elem;
function quoteNext(){
    quote_i = Math.floor(Math.random()*quote_array.length);
    quote_elem.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout("quoteSlide()",5000);
}
function quoteSlide(){
    quote_elem.innerHTML = quote_array[quote_i];
    quote_elem.style.opacity = 1;
    setTimeout("quoteNext()",5000);
}
</script>
```

small HTML part:

```
<blockquote id="quote"></blockquote>
```

Comment: Does quotenext() ever get called?

Comment: I forgot to mention, yes it is

Comment: Right after the blockquote
<blockquote id="quote"></blockquote>
                 <p id="quoteName"></p>
                    <script>quote_elem = document.getElementById("quote");quoteSlide();</script>

Comment: The first two line in your script need to be reversed as quote_array is undefined in line 1.

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyy much <3!